# submit the title of a selected row in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a web app using Django as backend and normal HTML as frontend.
For pagination, I used datatable, but the pagination come across after all the data load in the page, so it is a bit slow.

When select the row of a table, it's highlighted in mycase, how could I submit the title of the selected row ?

```
<form  ref="form" id="myform" method="post" action="/tag_course/">
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Material Title</th>
                <th>Author/Editor</th>
                <th>Edition</th>
                   <th>iSBN</th>
                <th>e-iSBN/VBID</th>
                <th>Material Format</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for book in query_results_book.all  %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.author }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.edition }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.isbn }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.e_isbn }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.Format_issued }}</td>
                               </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
<button class="button2"  onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({info: false, bLengthChange: false});
        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
         $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            }
            else {
                table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
        });
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to achieve this and among all of them the easiest way is to add a custom `data-attr` in your table td like:

```
<tr>
    <td data-title="Title">{{ book.title }}</td>
    <td data-title="Author">{{ book.author }}</td>
    <td data-title="Edition">{{ book.edition }}</td>
    <td data-title="ISBN">{{ book.isbn }}</td>
    <td data-title="E ISBN">{{ book.e_isbn }}</td>
    <td data-title="Format Issued ">{{ book.Format_issued }}</td>
</tr>
```

and get this `data-title` value using code like:

```
$(this).find('td').attr('data-title');
```

or

```
$(this).find('td').data('title');
```

Comment: how to make sure $(this) is the one I selected?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check now. FYI: you are using the same logic to handle `selected` class toggle and with that the above logic given by me will also work.